# ArgumentError (invalid date) in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this ArgumentError (invalid date)
 error and can't figure out what's causing it. The method is called from javascript.

```
  def loadDay
     @first_day_of_week = Date.strptime("{ params[:year].to_s, :params[:month].to_s, params[:day].to_s }", "{ %Y, %m, %d }")

     ...
  end
```

The log looks like this:

```
  Started GET "/planner/loadDay?day=7&month=5&year=2011" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-15 10:19:43 +0200
  Processing by PlannerController#loadDay as */*
  Parameters: {"day"=>"7", "month"=>"5", "year"=>"2011"}
  Completed   in 1ms
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you please post the trace?

Comment: You don't need to build a string and parse it afterwards (you are doing and reversing your work). It will be easier and faster if you use `Date.new(params[:year], :params[:month], params[:day])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a few `#{}` for string interpolation in the first argument to `Date.strptime`. I think you mean to say this:

```
Date.strptime("{ #{params[:year]}, #{params[:month]}, #{params[:day]} }", "{ %Y, %m, %d }")
```

Your call was just passing this literal string to `strptime`:

```
"{ params[:year].to_s, :params[:month].to_s, params[:day].to_s }"
```

and, without the values from `params` substituted in, `strptime` didn't know what you were talking, got upset, and raised an `ArgumentError` exception to indicate an "invalid date".

And you don't need the `to_s` calls inside `#{}` as `#{}` does that for you and the values in `params` will be strings anyway (unless, of course, you're doing some extra processing of `params` beyond what Rails normally does).